# При повторном открытии модального окна не срабатывает анимация

Tags: javascript, css

В общем, вроде бы в заголовке объяснил проблему. В интернете не нашёл ответа или я просто плохо гуглю :( Буду очень благодарен за ответы)

```js
const modalBtnHire = document.querySelector('#modalBtnHire');
const modalContentHire = document.querySelector('#modalContentHire');
const modalCloseHire = document.querySelector('#modalCloseHire');
const openModalHire = document.querySelector('.modal-inner');

modalBtnHire.onclick = function () {
    modalContentHire.classList.add('show');
    setInterval(function () {
        openModalHire.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    });
}

modalCloseHire.onclick = function () {
    modalContentHire.classList.remove('show');
}
```

```css
.btn-hire {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    height: 70px;
    
    text-align: center;    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    line-height: 70px;

    background-color: #00897B;
    
    position: relative;
    transition: color .5s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn-hire:before {
    content: '';
    width: 300px;
    height: 170px;
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #1ac0c5;
    z-index: -1;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -19%;
    
    transition: all .6s ease-in;
}

.btn-hire:hover:before {
    top: -60px;
}




.modal {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    /* opacity: 0; */

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 200000;
}

.modal.show {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-inner {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 25px;

    text-align: center;

    background-color: #fff;

    position: relative;

    transform: scale(.5);
    transition: transform .3s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.modal-close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;

    position: absolute;
    top: -37px;
    right: -30px;
}

.modal-close span {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px 0;

    background-color: #fff;
    transform-origin: center;
}

.modal-close span:first-child,
.modal-close span:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

.modal-close span:first-child {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-close span:last-child {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal.show {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-btn-hire">
                        <a href="#" class="btn-hire" id="modalBtnHire">hire is now</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    
<div class="modal" id="modalContentHire">
        <div class="modal-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto eveniet quaerat quam nam corporis doloremque neque, nobis magni. Consectetur nulla officiis impedit corporis dolorum, sequi cupiditate vel minus modi explicabo?</p>

            <div class="modal-close" id="modalCloseHire">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <!-- <img src="/Практика/CenterLogistic/img/modal-window/close.svg" alt=""> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JavaScript нужно только добавлять / убирать классы, всё остальное надо делать в CSS

```js
const modalBtnHireNode = document.querySelector('#modalBtnHire');
const modalNode = document.querySelector('#modal-1');
const modalCloseNode = modalNode.querySelector('.modal-close');
const modalInnerNode = modalNode.querySelector('.modal-inner');

modalBtnHireNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modalNode.classList.add('modal_show');
});

modalCloseNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modalNode.classList.remove('modal_show');
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-hire {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color: #00897B;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .5s ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn-hire::before {
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1ac0c5;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -19%;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in;
}

.btn-hire:hover::before {
  transform: translateY(-80%);
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.modal_show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal_show .modal-inner {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal-inner {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: transform .3s ease-out,
              opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.modal-close {
  --colorBoxShadow: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 6;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px var(--colorBoxShadow);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal-close:hover {
  --colorBoxShadow: white;
}

.modal-close__svg {
  --size: 30px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-btn-hire">
  <a href="#" class="btn-hire" id="modalBtnHire">hire is now</a>
</div>


<div class="modal" id="modal-1">

  <div class="modal-close">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="modal-close__svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="5px"  stroke="white">
      <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="100" />
      <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="100" y2="0" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto eveniet quaerat quam nam corporis doloremque neque, nobis magni. Consectetur nulla officiis impedit corporis dolorum, sequi cupiditate vel minus modi explicabo?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

у вас рабочий код, есть только 2 исправления которые надо сделать

1. Заменить `setInterval` на `setTimeout` потому что `setInterval` отрабатывает несколько раз, `setTimeout` только один
2. Вернуть `transform`  в исходное состояние `openModalHire.style.transform = 'scale(0)';`

```js
const modalBtnHire = document.querySelector('#modalBtnHire');
const modalContentHire = document.querySelector('#modalContentHire');
const modalCloseHire = document.querySelector('#modalCloseHire');
const openModalHire = document.querySelector('.modal-inner');

modalBtnHire.onclick = function () {
    modalContentHire.classList.add('show');
    setTimeout(function () {
        openModalHire.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    });
}

modalCloseHire.onclick = function () {
    modalContentHire.classList.remove('show');
    openModalHire.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
}
```

```css
.btn-hire {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    height: 70px;
    
    text-align: center;    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    line-height: 70px;

    background-color: #00897B;
    
    position: relative;
    transition: color .5s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn-hire:before {
    content: '';
    width: 300px;
    height: 170px;
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #1ac0c5;
    z-index: -1;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -19%;
    
    transition: all .6s ease-in;
}

.btn-hire:hover:before {
    top: -60px;
}




.modal {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    /* opacity: 0; */

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 200000;
}

.modal.show {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-inner {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 25px;

    text-align: center;

    background-color: #fff;

    position: relative;

    transform: scale(.5);
    transition: transform .3s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.modal-close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;

    position: absolute;
    top: -37px;
    right: -30px;
}

.modal-close span {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px 0;

    background-color: #fff;
    transform-origin: center;
}

.modal-close span:first-child,
.modal-close span:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

.modal-close span:first-child {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-close span:last-child {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal.show {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-btn-hire">
                        <a href="#" class="btn-hire" id="modalBtnHire">hire is now</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    
<div class="modal" id="modalContentHire">
        <div class="modal-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto eveniet quaerat quam nam corporis doloremque neque, nobis magni. Consectetur nulla officiis impedit corporis dolorum, sequi cupiditate vel minus modi explicabo?</p>

            <div class="modal-close" id="modalCloseHire">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <!-- <img src="/Практика/CenterLogistic/img/modal-window/close.svg" alt=""> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```